# Nonblocking PostgreSQL ORM

Tags: python, postgresql, scrapy, twisted

I have a web scraper using Scrapy, which is built on Twisted using Deferreds. For each page scraped I want to insert to several different tables in a PostgreSQL database. I would like this insertion to be nonblocking. Is there a way to get nonblocking Postgres interaction with an ORM like SQLAlchemy?

I understand there is nonblocking Postgres interaction with `alchimia` or `txpostgres`, but neither offers ORM functionality. If the answer is it's not possible, I'll use one of those. Is one of them preferred over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way an ORM is built in Python is generally not amenable to asynchronous operation.

A primary feature of Python ORMs that seems to be attractive is apparently normal attribute access to get and set values.  However, both of these present problems.

For attribute access to operate asynchronously, the obvious behavior is for something like `database_object.some_field` to evaluate to a `Deferred`.  Then the application would wait on this to receive the actual value.  The code ends up looking something like:

```
d = database_object.some_field
def got_some_field(result):
    print("DB obj some_field = {}".format(result))
d.addCallback(got_some_field)
```

Instead of a simple expression, you've got four lines of code.  One could argue that this has entirely destroyed the value the ORM is meant to provide.  It *may* be possible to work around this problem by pre-loading values from the database.  However, it's not always desirable to pre-load everything (it can harm performance) and it's not always obvious it's correct to do so (if you start a transaction, pre-load some values, execute an operation that might change those values, then retrieve them from the Python object, what should happen?).

Updating values is even worse.  Whereas a synchronous ORM might let you:

```
database_object.some_field = 3
```

How would an asynchronous ORM work for something similar?  Assignment can't produce a value at all.  So you need another inconvenient pattern to be able to do updates correctly.  Something like:

```
d = database_object.update("some_field", 3)
def updated(ignored):
    # Continue ...
d.addCallback(updated)
```

Or a very complicated system to do this behind the scenes in a way that doesn't allow for inconsistency between values in the database and values in memory in Python.  It's probably not impossible but the degree of complexity involved may be why no one seems to have tackled the problem.

Comment: Thank you; this is very interesting. [This `twistar` tutorial](http://findingscience.com/twistar/) seems to suggest they have developed some approach to this problem. How does that fit into the framework you've laid out?

Comment: I think twistar is a little lower-level than an ORM - it's an "active record pattern" implementation, which is useful for _building_ an ORM but it's missing a lot of what most people would consider part of an ORM.  For example, you _don't_ have attribute-access based data access - you have get and set methods instead, along with an explicit (single-object) "save" method.  And it accepts the notion that the Python objects and database will be inconsistent for a while (until you save changes).  Therefore, apps must take care not to be surprised by query results not reflecting un-"save"d changes.

Comment: (But take that with a grain of salt - my last real look at twistar was probably half a dozen years ago).

Answer (score 0):

A package named "postgresql-orm" has default connector class with **connection pool** and uses first free connection from pool per request:

```py
# pip install postgresql-orm
# pip install psycopg2-binary

import sql

import logging as log
log.basicConfig(level=log.DEBUG) # To see executed queries


sql.db = sql.Db('dbname=postgres user=postgres password=1234 host=127.0.0.1 port=5432', 
                size=20) # It will work with separate 20 connections in this case


class ParsedItem:
    pass

class Table(sql.Table):
    type = ParsedItem
    name = 'parsed_item'
    fields = {
        'id': {'type': 'int'},
        'some_field_1': {}
        'some_field_2': {}
    }

Table.add({
    'some_field_1': 'Some value 1',
    'some_field_2': 'Some value 2',
})
```

Documentation here: https://pypi.org/project/postgresql-orm/